# What is z rotation in unity 2D?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I thought that 2d has no z axis. As a result, I wonder why unity 2d includes freeze rotation z in rigidbody2D? If I don't check it, my object will rotate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with 2D on Unity is pretty much like working with 3D. You can even use Colliders and Meshes that are 3D on a 2D game. You can also use the transform tool to play with depth on your game Objects, modifying the Z-axis to align your GameObjects in order ("Houses" on the back, "Player" on the front, for example).

Even if you are using the 2D workspace, Unity let's you change that on the editor and see your scene from a 3D perspective.

[image: Unity editor.]

So freezing the Z-axis movement or rotation is important because you are actually working in a 3D game where you can only see the X and Y axis.

Answer (score 0):

In standard 2D space, you can only rotate objects on the forward vector which is the Z axis.

[image: img]